# Ubuntu Server Installer fails with OSError

Tags: server, system-installation

I’m trying to set up a dual-boot with an old Windows 8.1 computer and Ubuntu Server Long-Term edition. After going through the installation progress, I repeatedly get the same below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ... Truncated
    File "/snap/subiquity/1093/lib/python3.6/site-packages/curtin/block/__init__.py", line 1061, in exclusive_open
        fd = os.open(path, flags)
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/sda4'
```

The only thing that changes in the above error message each time is the number after the `sda`

`sda` is my hard drive.

I have spent the past 5 hours getting the same error message. I have tried deleting, shrinking, and growing all kinds of partitions. Please tell me any additional information I can provide, as I am very inexperienced with Linux and have no idea what’s going on.

Comment: `sda` is my hard drive.

Comment: Yes, but what is /dev/sda4, partition 4 on that drive? Is it a swap partition, _ext4_, or some other format? What is it used for? Please click [edit] and revise the question to show that information.